# Exporting data to new table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

This is my script and I need to create a new attribute table which contain the information on the `print` line. Could someone help me?

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import datetime

env.workspace= "C:/temp/temp.gdb"   
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fc_pnt = "C:/temp/temp.gdb/point"  
fc_buf = "C:/temp/temp.gdb/poly"

max_dist = 300
final_bff = "C:/temp/temp.gdb/final_bff"
final_ins = "C:/temp/temp.gdb/final_ins"
fields_buff = ["SHAPE@","id_local"]
fields = ["OID@", "SHAPE@AREA"]
fields_final = ["Shape_Area", "SC_11"]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc_pnt,fields_buff) as curs:
    for row in curs:
        pnt_cc = row[0]
        id_local = row[1]
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(pnt_cc, final_bff, str(max_dist))

        for i in fc_buf:
            arcpy.Intersect_analysis([fc_buf,final_bff],final_ins,"ALL","","INPUT")

            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(final_ins, fields_final) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
# i need to pass this print to a new table
                    print(str(id_local) + " " + "{0}, {1},".format(row[0], row[1] ))
```

Comment: Not an answer, but your last line would be better as: print("{0}, {1}, {2}.".format(id_local, row[0], row[1] ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write your last print line to a csv and import it to arc. I am not sure what you doing with the formatting by try something like this after your print statement.

```
import csv
```

code...

```
#print(str(id_local) + " " + "{0}, {1},".format(row[0], row[1] )) 
line = str(id_local)+','+str(row[0])+','+str(row[1])+','+'\n'
with open('csvfilename.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write(line)
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an insertCursor in your destination table.

Check out ESRI help [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/fr/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) ; it also has code examples.

If you mean to update an existing table, the updateCursor might also help - available [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/fr/help/main/10.1/index.html#/na/018w00000014000000/).